# Sapling addon - Is it possible to have controls for split levels over 4?

Tags: modeling, add-on, sapling-addon

I'm making a tree with split level 5.

Unfortunately Sapling addon give control only on 4 levels of branches. I assume level 5 only inherit some of the setting of first 4 levels.

I would like to have options for level 5+ if it possible at all. At least number or branches on level 5. Maybe there is some alterations i can enable in the script itself to show setting for level 5+. Or some other method?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `levels` property is defined around line 295 of `2.78/scripts/addons/add_curve_sapling/__init__.py`

```
    levels = IntProperty(name='Levels',
        description='Number of recursive branches (Levels)',
        min=1,
        max=6,
        soft_max=4,
        default=3, update=update_tree)
```

As you can see only soft_max is defined as 4, meaning you can slide past, or because it's pretty heavy duty going beyond 4, just type in 5 or 6 and WAIT.